# Changes to the name of Hashem in written texts

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, mesorah-tradition, safrus

I have seen an [article](http://www.oocities.org/hebrew_roots/html/hr-2-1-02.html) which cites a text called [Massorah](https://levendwater.org/companion/append30.html) and this text supposedly catalogs 134 instances (referenced [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98602/in-what-manner-how-did-hashem-appear-to-avraham-at-mamre-gen-181)) in which the written text "originally" used the 4 letter name of Hashem but the soferim changed the wording to be a-d-n-y. The article and its source material use the Masoretic notes as explained [here](https://www.ancientjewreview.com/read/2020/9/11/introduction-to-the-masorah-the-masorah-of-biblia-hebraica-quinta-bhq).

I asked someone to take a look at the list and he worked with Sefer Yeshayahu in the Isaiah A Scroll while I looked at the Leningrad [Codex](https://archive.org/details/Leningrad_Codex/page/n446/mode/2up?ref=ol&view=theater&q=isaiah).

While he feels that the number is inflated (he found that 4:4 in the Isaiah scroll already had a-d-n-y so no change is reflected) there are certainly situations in which he says that the Isaiah scroll has the 4 letter name but the codex has a-d-n-y.

The article I linked to suggests categories of situations in which soferim changed things but I don't know if that has any foundation.

Is there any Jewish source that discusses why there was a change in the cases where the codex has the word and the earlier scroll has the 4 letter name?

Comment: Ginsburg's list of 134 places where אדני appears (without יהוה next to it). In some of these cases, he notes differences between the various manuscript traditions, and Ginsburg writes that we can "safely assume" that there were changes from יהוה to אדני. But he doesn't extrapolate to the entire list of 134.

Comment: @magicker72 this thread seems to undermine the 134 number but still leaves the fact that there are some changes unexplored https://b-hebrew.ibiblio.narkive.com/cBK0Olbr/ginsburg-emmendations-of-yhwh